# server shutdown when import sql data

Tags: azerothcore

Use the newest code to compiled.
When running the worldserver ,it has a error and shutdown.
Here is the error in the log .

> Updating World database...
> Duplicate filename "E:/AzerotherCore/data/sql/archive/db_world/6.x/2022_01_22_00.sql" occurred. Because updates are ordered by their filenames, every name needs to be unique!
> Could not update the World database, see log for details.

If I rename the sql file, the massage comes below

> Updating Auth database...
>
> > It seems like the update "2022_01_23_03.sql" '6291006' was renamed, but the old file is still there! Treating it as a new file! (It is probably an unmodified copy of the file "2022_01_23_00.sql")

Then I check the file with same name in "data\sql\updates" and "data\sql\archive", I found their code is the same ,too.
So, my question is :could I delete the sql files in "data\sql\archive" ，and then run the server without any potential issues?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that your config option Updates.ArchivedRedundancy has been enabled, if you disable it the worldserver will stop searching the Archived files.